# Designing WordPress Themes using Dreamweaver

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, dreamweaver

I've been trying to figure out how to properly setup DreamWeaver in such a way that I can create WordPress themes. Right now I'm running WordPress on localhost, accessing it via DreamWeaver. Then I'm using LiveView on the actual WordPress code and modifying the files in the theme folder.

What I'd really like to do, and I'm not sure if this is possible, is to visually see the theme and modify it without having to go back and forth between the wordpress theme and the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this resource: [Wp Themer](http://wpthemerkit.com/).  It doesn't even require WordPress to be up and running, and you can make use of your Dreamweaver skills to not go back and forth.  The kit includes all the styles you need and a sample page that contains all the pieces and parts of a WordPress site.